# How to trigger SMS on Emulator in windows emulator?

Tags: winapi, mobile, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have Experience in Mobile Testing. But i am new to Window Phone app testing through Windows Emulator.

Can some one Guide me to Trigger SMS through Emulator

Comment: do you mean "Sending SMS to yourself in the emulator" ?

Comment: @user3683136, yes, I want to send SMS to my on device which is there on the emulator. How to do that?

Comment: since comments are for information or just to have clear about question or for hint. its not for conversation so i couldn't answer your all question in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this its working:

```
    SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();
    smsComposeTask.To = "+14250010001";
    smsComposeTask.Body = "Hello";
    smsComposeTask.Show();
```

**Note**: The phone number for the emulator is “**+14250010001**“

for more Reference you can go here [Sending an SMS to yourself in the emulator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsmobile/archive/2004/04/27/121497.aspx)

Comment: @user3683139, Hi i am really fresher in this.. Can u please give me some more information regarding this..?? like steps..

Comment: refer this Article http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_send_an_SMS_in_Windows_Phone. just put Number as shown above.

Comment: thank you.. Actually i am expecting that.. i want to Send a message to my Emulator, without writing any code. I am asking for Testing purpose. do u have any tips for this..?

Comment: just go to SMSCompose and try with above number and type message, send it. it works.

Comment: Can you guide me how to trigger a call to device in the Emulator?

Comment: here i have some more questions.. please address those Questions also. Thanks in Advance

1.How can Check Network issues in the Emulators?
2.I want to Check the Low Memory of the Device, How can i reduce the Memory Size of the Device in the Emulator?
3.